# 自動キーワード生成正規表現

Tags: php, 正規表現

Webページ上で特定の文字にリンクをつける正規表現を探しています。

以下のページを参考にしました。
http://am-yu.net/2012/03/19/auto_keyword_link_php/

しかし、こちらの正規表現では、タグの属性の文字列にキーワードが含まれていた場合、正規表現に引っかかってしまい生成されるHTMLが崩れてしまいます。

崩れないような正規表現、もしくは、別の対処法を教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1):

置換する文字列を元のHTML文書全体ではなく、
jsでDOMを走査し、内容のみを変換していきましょう。